# Filtering a BindingSource based on the number of child rows

Tags: c#, .net, data-binding, filter, ado.net

I'm working on my first little Database application where I use a typed `DataSet` and data binding:

[image]

I have a `customersBindingSource` to bind the list of customers to the `ListBox` on the left and an `allowedclientsBindingSource` to bind the list of allowed clients (of the selected customer) to the `DataGridView` on the right.

Now I'd like to apply a filter so that only disabled clients are shown on the right. I can do that by setting

```
allowedclientsBindingSource.Filter = "Enabled = 'false'";
```

and this works fine. Now not all customers have disabled clients. And I want to show only those customers on the left which actually have disabled clients. So I'm looking for something like this:

```
customersBindingSource.Filter = "numberOfAllowedClients > 0";
```

Of course this `numberOfAllowedClients` must refer to the *filtered* list of allowed clients.

What is the correct filter expression to achieve this?

**Edit:**

If possible I'd like to keep using data binding and not filling the `ListBox` manually.

What I found is that I can filter the customers list based on the number of child rows like this:

```
customersBindingSource.Filter = "Count(Child.AllowedClientID) > 0";
```

but it uses the unfiltered list of clients. I also tried:

```
customersBindingSource.Filter = "Count(Child.Enabled = 'false') > 0";
```

but this doesn't work since no expressions are allowed in the `Count` aggregate. I also tried to set the `RowFilter` property on the `DefaultView` of the data table instead of on the binding source. But that didn't work either.

Is there really no clean and easy solution for this without doing it manually?

Answer (score 1):

You can use LINQ to create a temporary data table to use as the data source.

Build the customer table:

```
DataTable Customer = new DataTable();
Customer.Columns.Add("CustomerID");
Customer.Columns.Add("Name");

DataRow Stefan = Customer.NewRow();
Stefan["CustomerID"] = 1;
Stefan["Name"] = "Stefan";
Customer.Rows.Add(Stefan);

DataRow Robert = Customer.NewRow();
Robert["CustomerID"] = 2;
Robert["Name"] = "Robert";
Customer.Rows.Add(Robert);

DataRow William = Customer.NewRow();
William["CustomerID"] = 3;
William["Name"] = "William";
Customer.Rows.Add(William);
```

Build the client table:

```
DataTable Client = new DataTable();
Client.Columns.Add("ClientID");
Client.Columns.Add("CustomerID");
Client.Columns.Add("Enabled");

DataRow Client1 = Client.NewRow();
Client1["ClientID"] = 1;
Client1["CustomerID"] = 1;
Client1["Enabled"] = true;
Client.Rows.Add(Client1);

DataRow Client2 = Client.NewRow();
Client2["ClientID"] = 2;
Client2["CustomerID"] = 2;
Client2["Enabled"] = true;
Client.Rows.Add(Client2);

DataRow Client3 = Client.NewRow();
Client3["ClientID"] = 3;
Client3["CustomerID"] = 2;
Client3["Enabled"] = false;
Client.Rows.Add(Client3);

DataRow Client4 = Client.NewRow();
Client4["ClientID"] = 4;
Client4["CustomerID"] = 3;
Client4["Enabled"] = false;
Client.Rows.Add(Client4);
```

Filter the client table for enabled = false:

```
BindingSource ClientBS = new BindingSource();
ClientBS.DataSource = Client;
ClientBS.Filter = "Enabled = false";
```

Use LINQ to join the two tables and return only customer rows with disabled clients:

```
var CustomersWithDisabledClients = from client in Client.AsEnumerable()
                                   from customer in Customer.AsEnumerable()
                                   where Convert.ToInt32(customer["CustomerID"]) == Convert.ToInt32(client["CustomerID"]) &&
                                   Convert.ToBoolean(client["Enabled"]) == false
                                   select new { CustomerID = customer["CustomerID"], Name = customer["Name"] };
```

Clone the customer table and add the rows of customers with disabled clients to use with your binding source:

```
DataTable filteredCustomer = Customer.Clone();
CustomersWithDisabledClients.ToList().ForEach(r => filteredCustomer.Rows.Add(r));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I still hope to get an easier solution that works with data binding (see my edit).